# In ArangoDb, does choice of collection impact performance?

Tags: performance, collections, arangodb

I was wondering.

You can throw anything in any collection in Arango. I can imagine however that placing objects with similar attributes in the same collection has impact on indexing, which impacts performance.

Is that true or shouldn't I worry about performance when creating collections?

tnx, Frank

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to worry about performance and collections so much.

You design your performance largely by indexing your data according to the planned queries and choosing the proper index for the above. But your query performance are going to again be hugely affected by filtering the data before sorting and vice versa.

This is all as long as you are on a single server instance. Once you are looking at sharding your data over many cluster nodes, you can again boost or impair the performance.

tldr: Don't worry about collections before you have worried about your queries and your indexes.